# iPhone Orientation Change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I know how to do an orientation change, but lets say you have a view with buttons, labels, ect.  The autoresizing distorts and makes the view look strange.  What's the accepted way to do this, do I just create a portrait and landscape view.  If so where would I actually do the swapping of these views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all kind of resizing  and reposition in your `layoutSubviews` method of `UIView`.
Once the orientation is changed, your `layoutSubviews` would be called then you can know the current orientation by using `UIDevice` class. and reposition your views child accordingly

`UIDevice` property to be used for getting current orientation .

```
@propertyic,readonly) UIDeviceOrientation orientation
```

Answer (score 0):

My sandbox app:
https://github.com/comonitos/programatical_device_orientation

The solution is easy